# 127.0.0.1/admin page "Not Found"

Tags: magento2, admin, installation, 404-page

I'm installing Magento2

After I reached to **`"127.0.0.1/setup/#/success"`** and clicked **`"Launch Magento Admin"`** I got the **"Not Found"** page.

I'm sure that I have changed the administrator page to **"admin"** ... that is also appeared in the success page.

If I try to open just **127.0.0.1** the page opens, but broken.... and if I click on any link in that page it takes me to the **"Not Found" page**

I,m using **Apache/2.4.18 and php 5.6**

If you have a solution ... please use simple words and clear steps ... I'm not that deep in this

Comment: try with 127.0.0.1/index.php/admin

Comment: Or check admin frontName in file app/etc/local.xml

Comment: Or try with localhost/admin Or localhost/index.php/admin

Comment: I've tried all of that but all took me to the "Not Found" page.
But where is that app/etc/local.xml ... where can I find it? ... if what do you mean should be under var/www/Magento2/app/etc, then there is no local.xml there !

Comment: if this is magento2 related question then add tag magento 2 or mention magento 2 in your question

Comment: app/etc/local.xml is for magento 1.X version not sure for magento 2

Comment: so ... any solution for Magento 2?

Answer (score 1):

I was also faced with this issue and managed to solve it with the help of [this site](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-mod_rewrite-for-apache-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Here's where it comes down to:

**First: enable mod_rewrite:**

1. open terminal
2. enable mod_rewrite
3. restart apache2

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo systemctl restart apache2

**Secondly: adjust your .conf file:**

1. locate your .conf file
2. add the `<Directory ...>` code
3. restart apache2

> ls /etc/apache2/sites-available
>
> sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Add this code below the  tag:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

> sudo systemctl restart apache2

**And now you should be able to surf to your own admin page**

*Note: you'll probably use the `000-default.conf`, unless you have set up a different VirtualHost. In that case you need to change the `000-default.conf` with your own VirtualHost.conf file and change the `/var/www/html` to point to your own public_html directory.*

*Note2: use `ctrl-o` in nano to save a file and `ctrl-x` to close it.*

Comment: enable mod_rewrite solution worked for me!!

Answer (score 0):

> **127.0.0.1/** is the default localhost address and the root of your localhost server directory.

The best solution for your problem is to:

- Move your Magento Files to a Directory inside the localhost root. (Assuming you are using XAMPP)

Let's say we name it as **"magentoshop"**, so your Magento Files will be stored inside this directory with this Directory structure: **C:\xampp\htdocs\magentoshop**

And you can access your **magentoshop admin** on url like this:

> **127.0.0.1/magentoshop/admin**